# converting feet-inch string DataFrame column to centimeters

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, series

I have a column of basketball players height:

```
0       6-10
1        6-9
2        7-2
3        6-1
4        6-6
        ... 
4545    6-11
4546     7-1
4547     6-1
4548     7-1
4549     6-3
```

I want to convert the values from feet to cm.
I made a split: `player_data['height'].str.split('-')`, and received a Series of arrays with separate feet and inches:

```
0       [6, 10]
1        [6, 9]
2        [7, 2]
3        [6, 1]
4        [6, 6]
         ...   
4545    [6, 11]
4546     [7, 1]
4547     [6, 1]
4548     [7, 1]
4549     [6, 3]
```

Now I try to convert values to float:

```
df = player_data['height'].str.split('-').astype(float)
```

But I receive an error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the ultimate desired output? You want a string with values in cm?

Comment: You're trying to convert a list `[6,10]` to a float but it's not clear how that should be done so you get an error. do you want the outcome to be `6.10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your end goal is to convert the "feet-inch" values to cm, I would do:

```
df['height_cm'] = (df['height'].str.extract('(\d*)-(\d*)')
                   .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') # or .astype(int)
                   .mul([30.48, 2.54]).sum(axis=1)
                  )
```

Output:

```
     height  height_cm
0      6-10     208.28
1       6-9     205.74
2       7-2     218.44
3       6-1     185.42
4       6-6     198.12
4545   6-11     210.82
4546    7-1     215.90
4547    6-1     185.42
4548    7-1     215.90
4549    6-3     190.50
```